# Why do SD cards perform so much better than SSDs in space?

Tags: radiation, flight-computer

SD cards and SSDs are based on the same technologies, so why the stark differences in performance?

Recently, it was reported that after a year in space, half of the SSD drives on the HPE Spaceborne computer had been fried. This suggests that SSDs are not suitable for use in space.

In contrast, SD cards have been used successfully for years. They are commonly used by virtually all of the photography cameras on board the ISS, and have performed perfectly. They are also used by small satellites. Somehow, they do not seem to experience these issues. Why?

Comment: Could you add a link to the source you're describing?

Comment: It might be a difference in the enclosures used, not the media.

Comment: @JCRM ISS is a pretty massive enclosure compared to a small satellite. 
Could anybody point to any studies that prove the claims in the question?

Comment: size isn't everything @asdfex

Comment: Discussion here: https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=36557.20 would seem to indicate that SD cards fail very regularly as well.

Comment: Here's an excellent source on consumer flash radiation tolerance: https://trs.jpl.nasa.gov/handle/2014/42663

Comment: While both may have FLASH memory, there's no guarantee it's *the same exact kind* of FLASH. Also an SSD may have other electronics to manage the memory and make it perform the way a hard drive needs to perform (speed, latency, etc.), whereas an SD card is far simpler inside.

Comment: In fact many of the small satellite failure had been due to SD Card. But I guess large proportion of them were due to mechanical failure of SD Card holding structure.

Comment: This sounds hopelessly vendor-specific and exact-chipset-specific to me.

SSDs are often using much higher-performance controllers than SD cards, I suspect.